# Is there any way to find unmatched character using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, function, match

recently I found that we can find all vowels character using regex function like this

```
const vowel = str.match(/[aiueo]/gi);
```

But is there any way to find all non vowels character using this match function?

So when I have word "thanks"

It will count all non vowel character length, so the result will be 5

Maybe anyone would share this information, I was trying to find in google, but still not found any good solution

Thanks

Comment: `/[^aiueo]/gi` - note the `^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `^` character in front of a character set negates the set

```
const notVowel = str.match(/[^aiueo]/gi);
```